# Detect if user is browsing in private mode

Tags: google-chrome, flash, silverlight, private, incognito-mode

I know there are already other threads dealing with this very topic. But most of them are already a few months old and their common conclusion seems to be: *"It's not possible to detect if a user is browsing in private mode or not."*

Yet some days ago I tried watching a film using Amazon Instant Video and was confronted with an DRM error (#3365) pointing out that it was forbidden to watch Amazon's videos in the browser's incognito mode.

If it is of interest:

- OS: Win7
- Browser: Chrome 41

Could there be a correlation with this [Ooyala issue](http://community.ooyala.com/t5/Ooyala-Player-Knowledge-Base/Ooyala-videos-will-not-play-while-in-quot-Incognito-Mode-quot-of/ta-p/4455) where user 'thomas' states

> The problem occurs because Google has made the Pepper Flash plugin as it's primary flash plug-in for the Chrome browser.

Or might it rather be related to Silverlight?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Craigslist determine if you are in Incognito mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947360/how-does-craigslist-determine-if-you-are-in-incognito-mode)