# How does Craigslist determine if you are in Incognito mode

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to detect whether a user is in incognito mode when they visit a webpage.

If you visit http://boston.craigslist.org/gbs/fud/5127255934.html in a normal session and click on the `reply` button, you will not get hit with recaptcha. But if you do the same when in Incognito mode, recaptcha box appears.

How does Craigslist achieve this? What properties does it check?

Comment: It has nothing to do with incognito, it's just that in "incognito mode" nothing is stored, like cookies and localStorage, so there's no way for any website to remember you, and they have to revalidate on every pageload.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately craigslist doesn't check anything.

Incognito mode ignores any previously saved cache, cookies, history, etc, and acts as if you've never been to the site before.

Notice that if you complete the captcha, and revisit the site again in the same session (don't close the tab) after visiting a different site, it won't ask again.

---

A quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy_mode):

> Privacy mode or "private browsing" or "incognito mode" is a privacy feature in some web browsers to disable browsing history and the web cache. This allows a person to browse the Web without storing local data that could be retrieved at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

Incognito mode treats the user as if it has never visited the site before - so it ignores the browsers cache, cookies, history etc. What you're witnessing is just a side effect of this behavior